# Running Java Servlet cant view welcome page 404 error

Tags: java, servlets

Having an issue like this.

```
Error 404--Not Found

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.5 404 Not Found
```

[image]

### `web.xml`

Here is my `..\MTSM\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml`

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ActionAdet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ActionSure</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

### `mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml`

Here is my `..\MTSM\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml`

```xml
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

### `hello.jsp`

Here is my `..\MTSM\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\pages\hello.jsp`

```
    $.get('ActionAdet', {opername: 'services'}, function (responseJson) { } ) ;..
```

### `hello.HelloController.java`

Here is my `..\MTSM\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\HelloController.java`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "ss";
    }
}
```

### `ActionAdet.java`

Here is my `..\MTSM\src\main\java\com\springapp\mvc\ActionAdet.java`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ActionAdet")
public class ActionAdet extends HttpServlet { } etc..
```

I can't view my project in this url: `localhost:7001/MTSM/`

and also not available in: `localhost:7001/MTSM/hello.jsp`

It was working 2 days ago. I think I'm deleted something in `web.xml`, but I don't remember.
Do you know what problem is?

[image]

I uploaded my project here: [Dropbox -- MTSM_20140112.zip][3]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>` (note the `/*`) in web.xml ?

Comment: try localhost:7001/mvc/

Comment: @SergeBallesta i did it now. nothing changed. #hubert boateng i tried it. still same. my url /MTSM/ im sure that is.

Comment: The most efficient way to understand what happens is to use debug logging for `org.springframework`, or at least `org.springframework.web` and to show logs.

Comment: A `Controller` is not a `HttpServlet`. The mapping is controlled by the `DispatcherServlet` not the `web.xml` remove the mapping for `/ActionAdet` and `/ActionSure` from your web.xml.

Comment: Remove all servlet mapping and add this <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> in you web.xml and then try.

Comment: web.xml pastie.org/9827302 || server.output http://pastie.org/9827332 nothing changed.. still 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the logs you provided in pastie (that's **bad** : you should have providen the relevant part as an edit), spring tried to load `WEB-INF/pages/ss.jsp` and did not find it. I means :

- you probably hit the controller `HelloController`
- the method `printWelcome` returned `ss` as a string
- due to `mvc-dispacher-servlet.xml`, `InternalResourceViewResolver` looked for `WEB-INF/pages/ss.jsp` (normal untill here)
- as the file does not exist you got a 404 error (still normal : it is not what you expected, but what you asked)

You should try to be coherent between view names returned by controller and actual jsp file :

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

should forward to view `WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp` (that exists according to you project image)

Comment: Thanks Serge! i'm fan of you now!^^